# XNA - Strange Texture Rendering Issue Using XNA BasicEffect

Tags: xna, 3d, textures

I have been reading and working through Riemers 3D XNA tutorials to expand my knowledge of XNA from 2D into 3D. Unfortunately I am having rendering issues that I am unable to solve and I need a point in the right direction.

[image: issue]

I am not expecting the Models to look identical to Blender but there is some serious discoloring from the texture files once rendering through XNA. The Character model is using completely incorrect colors (Red where Grey should be) and the Cube is rendering a strange pattern where a flat color should be drawn.

My sampling mode is set to PointClamp.

The Character model that I created has a 32 by 32 pixel texture that has been UV mapped to the model in blender. The model was then exported to .FBX. For the Cube Model a 64 by 64 pixel texture is used.

```
foreach (ModelMesh mesh in samuraiModel.Meshes)
{
    foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
    {
        effect.Projection = Projection;
        effect.View = View;
        effect.World = World;
    }
    mesh.Draw();
}
```

Does this look like it is caused by a mistake I made while UV Mapping or Creating Materials in Blender?
Is this a problem with using the default XNA BasicEffect? 
Or something completely different that i have not considered?

Thank You!